# Types of Ethernet Link Modes from ethtool

Tags: ethernet, lan, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet, wired-networking

What's the difference between the following link modes when we run `ethtool`:

1. Supported link modes
2. Advertised link modes
3. Link partner advertised link modes

There is a similar output from `mii-tool`:

1. Capabilities
2. Advertising
3. Link Partner

Please explain what these 3 link modes actually mean.
Also, does `Link Partner` mean the router that I'm connected to? Or it means the NIC?

If so, is there a way to find the link modes supported by the router? (Not the Ethernet card)

Comment: Questions should be based on appropriate research. Please share what you tried to answer your question and why you couldn't.

Comment: I tried searching for explanations for the listed 3 modes. Even the docs of the binary doesn't seem to have explained it. That's way I've raised a question :)

Answer (score 3):

When you connect two Ethernet NICs with a cable, for example your PC and your router, but also e.g. your PC and your laptop, the NICs perform [autonegotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) over the cable: They advertise the possible connection speeds and modes to the partner on the other end of the cable, and then both NICs choose the "best" speed and mode.

So the *supported link modes* are the modes that the hardware of the NIC that ethtool is interrogated can actually do. The *advertised modes* are the modes that are advertised to the partner on the other end over the cable, and the *link partner advertised modes* are the modes that the NIC at the other end is advertising over the cable.

Most routers run embedded linux, so you can find out the *supported* modes by getting root access to your router and running `ethtool` on the router. However, since normally the advertised modes will correspond to the supported modes (unless some are [impossible with the given cable](https://superuser.com/a/1245950/327880)), you can also just look at the link partner advertised modes as first approximation.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt. Makes sense now. This is the problem that I'm facing: My router is supports Giga-Ethernet, but that's not showing up in the `Link partner advertised modes`. As you said, I got root access into my router and tried `ethtool` but it wasn't present. But it seems there's only a minimal version of Busybox present, which is the source of most binaries. The arch is `armv71`. So I tried getting the latest Busybox binary for this arch and tried `lspci`, but didn't work. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: That should be a new question, but: (1) Please edit question with exact brand and model of router. (2) See router manual and/or OpenWRT documentation for this router for details on what ethernet chip is used, and what speeds it supports. (3) Verify (for example with two PCs known to be Giga-Ethernet capable) that the cable works. (4) Save current firmware of router somewhere, re-flash with open-source variant (OpenWRT etc.), use `ethtool` provided by open-source variant, restore old firmware (if needed).